# Yakuake Wayland refusing to hide on F12

Tags: kubuntu, wayland, yakuake

I'm running kubuntu 21.04 and decided to go with the new Kde available because it has vital feature control audio output to analog/HDMI directly in the sound applet. But it also broke X window session, anyway it runs pretty good with Wayland and decided to proceed. Only on the little issue here. Yakuake not autostarting and response only once at F12 after this it never hides but can be overlapped by other windows and I cant call it again on top or hide it just sit in back of my windows. Which eliminates the whole purpose of this terminal. Any workaround here? with X window it worked just fine

```
Version 21.04.3
KDE Frameworks 5.84.0,
Qt 5.15.2 (build 5.15.2),
wayland
```

Comment: Are you using Kubuntu 20.04? or Neon?   The Qt version you mention is **not** a LTS version, and not what comes with *focal* or 20.04, so if you were using Kubuntu 20.04 - you aren't anymore (only parts of your system are now *focal*).  You should check `ubuntu-security-status` as your system is not a LTS release any longer I hope you realize

Comment: My bad sorry its 21.04. Just typo. Corrected